# jQuery if element hasClass of var do this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display an element if it has a class equal to a variable but I can't seem to get it working.

My code:

HTML:

```
<a class="addme" title="showme" href="javascript:void(0)">hey</a>
<div class="list">
    <div class="hey">hide</div>
    <div class="hey showme">show</div>
    <div class="hey">hide</div>
</div>

<span></span>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    $('div').hide();

    $('.addme').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var x = $(this).attr('title');
      if ($('.hey').hasClass(x))      
      {
        $('.list ' + '.' + x).show();
        $('span').html('.list ' + '.' + x)
      }
    })
});
```

JSFIDDLE [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/mtd2pek9/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.showme` div actually gets displayed, but `.list` is hidden, since you use:

```
$('div').hide();
```

You need to specifiy this selector:

```
$('.list div').hide(); // e.g., can be a lot of things to work, depends on context
```

Also, you have some redundant code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.list div').hide();

    $('.addme').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var x = $(this).attr('title');
      $('.list ' + '.' + x).show();
      $('span').html('.list ' + '.' + x)
    })
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtd2pek9/2/)**

Comment: Argh, totally overlooked that! Thank you!